# Install4j installer fails with internal error for Mac OS

Tags: install4j

I have built an installer using the latest Install4J. On the Mac OS, it fails to install with the following message: "An internal error has occuerred (error code: launch path not accessible)".

The same installer for other platforms (Windows 32/64, and Linux) work fine. Has anyone else seen this and know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out, this error was caused by the OpenJDK JRE version i was using. It works fine with the Installed version of the JRE on my Mac.

Comment: In my case this was caused by using the same file name for Mac jre as for Windows. Silly me, blindly copy-pasting.